# Divs docked right without float

Tags: html, css

I've seen there are a couple questions similar to this one but none of them seem to solve my problem.

I want a very simple design:
Two or more divs stacked on top of each other, each of them docked to the right. I'm practicing for a test on which using the float property is not allowed.

```css
body{
        width:900px;
        height:850px;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }
    
    #header{
        width:900px;
        height: 225px;
        position: absolute;
        right:0px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }
    
    #cen{
        width: 900px;
        height: 240px;
        position: absolute;
        right:0px;
        border:1px solid orange;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
        
            <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
        
        </head>
        <body>
            
            <div id="header">
        
            </div>
        
            <div id="cen">
        
            </div>
        
        </body>
        </html>
```

Now, when I only had one div (header), this worked, it was docked right. But when I add the 'cen' div it is also docked right but, instead of going underneath the 'header' div, it just goes over it.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: because both header and cen were absolute elements

Comment: Okay, well, how do I achieve the design I want?
When I change them to relative they are stacked on top of each other but not docked right.

Comment: I've added my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute elements won't behave in a decent manner they won't bother any blocks in their ways.

Since the element header has a height you can add the cen element under it by giving `top:"whatever the height the header is"`

Here the height of the header is 225px

Stack the cen in a position of `top: 255px`  so it will be below the header.

Try this...

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
body{
    width:900px;
    height:850px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#header{
    width:900px;
    height: 225px;
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
    border:1px solid black;
    top:0;
}

#cen{
    width: 900px;
    height: 240px;
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:225px;
    border:1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />

</head>
<body>

    <div id="header">

    </div>

    <div id="cen">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well I guess that would work, but what if instead of two I had more divs? Would I then have to sum up the heights of all previous divs and set that to be the top of the next div? I'm not an expert but it just seems like there might be a better solution for this.

Comment: I don't think so absolute elements won't work the way you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Statically positioned block elements (divs) will stack like you describe by default. So there is no need for absolute positioning.

Also, there is no need to set a width because:

> A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).

```css
body {
  width: 900px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}

#header {
  height: 225px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#cen {
  height: 240px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">

</div>

<div id="cen">
</div>
```

Comment: I can see that it works, but what exactly makes them dock right in your code?

Comment: It's a combination of `width: 900px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: 0;` on body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for something like this:

```css
    .container {
        width:100vw;
        display:flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    .column {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction:column;
        flex-basis:33%;
    }
    .row {
        display: flex;
        background-color: red;
        width: 100%;
        flex-grow: 1;
        height: 100px; /* can be whatever you like */
        margin: .25rem;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="row"></div>
            <div class="row"></div>
            <div class="row"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

[CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) would probable work even better, but I haven't worked with it enough.